# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, connection-string, asp.net-web-api2

I have added my web api services on azure. For storing data I am using SQL Server.
My database too on azure. I am able to call services from client side. But when I try to make any database call (CRUD operations). It's giving me error.

```
Data":{"ClassName":"System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException","Message":"The underlying provider failed on Open.","Data":null,"InnerException":{"Errors":[{"source":".Net SqlClient Data Provider","number":-1,"state":0,"errorClass":20,"server":"","message":"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)","procedure":null,"lineNumber":0,"win32ErrorCode":-1}],"ClientConnectionId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","ClassName":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","Message":"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)","Data":{"HelpLink.ProdName":"Microsoft SQL Server","HelpLink.EvtSrc":"MSSQLServer","HelpLink.EvtID":"-1","HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl":"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink","HelpLink.LinkId":"20476"},"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nOnError\nSystem.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection\nVoid OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean, System.Action`1[System.Action])","HResult":-2146232060,"Source":".Net SqlClient Data Provider","WatsonBuckets":null},"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at JodoServices.Repositories.ClsLocation.getUserInfo(String userName)","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nOpen\nEntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection\nVoid Open()","HResult":-2146233087,"Source":"EntityFramework","WatsonBuckets":null}
```

It is giving me above error during calling SPROC in code.
My connection string is,

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="tcp:q89jcwtry3.database.windows.net,1433;Database=JodoData;User ID=keval-pc@q89jcwtry3;Password=myPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30" />   

<add name="JodoDataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:q89jcwtry3.database.windows.net;initial catalog=JodoData;integrated security=False;User ID=keval-pc@q89jcwtry3;Password=myPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Is there anything wrong with my JodoDataEntities connection string ?

Where do I need to change ?

Comment: Check if firewall on your client computer that is trying to establish connection to the sql server is configured to allow outbound port 1433 and 1434

Comment: Thanks for giving reply...
Can you tell me steps, how can I make setting in firewall...
Or please suggest me any article for that.

Comment: Open Control Panel - > Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings. Select outbound rules. Click on New Rule -> Port -> TCP. On Specific Remote ports enter 1433 -> Allow the connection. Enable all options for Domain, public and private networks. Enter name of the rule and Finish. Do the same step for port 1434